# PHPExcel write array formula

Tags: arrays, formula, phpexcel

I was wondering if there is a way of writing an array formula using

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1','=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A10),2)=0,1,0))');
```

or some other attribute.  As an array (CSE) formula, the result should be

```
ans=5
```

but I'm currently getting just a normal result as

```
ans=0
```

When I am looking through the code, I ran a

```
getDataType & getFormulaAttributes
```

but I cannot figure out how to use them.  I think there is a t=array somewhere needed, but I'm going cross-eyed now and I've already lost 3 strands of hair over this.